# Keyboard shortcut to focus/unfocus on flash element in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, shortcuts

I've recently started using the [Vimium plugin](http://vimium.github.com/) for Chrome to allow me for browsing the web using some common Vi(m) keyboard shortcuts.

The HTML5 video player used by Youtube can be controlled by some keyboard shortcuts. However, this only works once it is focused. Is there a way to focus/defocus on a flash element on general or the Youtube player in particular which will give me access to the built-in video player keyboard commands?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using YouTube [Leanback](http://www.youtube.com/leanback)? It's designed to be fully controlled with the keyboard (heck, even a TV remote).

Comment: No. It is a viable alternative (thank you), but I would prefer to be able to browse the "normal" pages in the manner I describe.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like fastscripts, override the shortcut of your liking.

An app like fastscripts listens globally (overrides both flash and chrome) but will act locally. It will do exactly what you want in this case.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "File"
                tell menu "File"
                    click menu item "Open Location…"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```